# How to switch an RxJS Oberservable<boolean> from true to false and vice versa

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm learning Angular and I have a pretty simple question : I have an Observable that I use to track if a side menu is closed or opened. I get to have my Observable to start with 'true' as a value, but I really don't get how I can swap it so it does this logic : `value = !value`

Here's my service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, startWith } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SideMenuService {
  private open$ = new Observable<boolean>().pipe(
    startWith<boolean>(true)
  );

  constructor() { }

  getOpen() {
    return this.open$;
  }

  swapOpen() {
    // Here I want to make open$ to be false
  }
}
```

And here's my Typescript file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SideMenuService } from "../../../services/side-menu/side-menu.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'side-menu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css']
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public open!: boolean;

  constructor(
    private sideMenuService: SideMenuService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sideMenuService.getOpen()
      .subscribe(result => this.open = result);
  }

  swtichTriggered(): void {
    this.sideMenuService.swapOpen();
  }
}
```

How can I toggle the value properly in the swapOpen() function?

Comment: Try using ```BehaviorSubject```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some RxJS operator magic via scan

(On mobile so forgive the formatting)

```
toggle$ = new Subject<void>()

// either subscribe or better yet use async pipe in component
isOpen$ = toggle$.pipe(
    // start with true then switch on toggle emission 
    scan((acc, _) => !acc, true)
)

toggle$.next() // triggers isOpen$ i.e. use in swapOpen

// don’t forget to clean up subscriptions
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a BehaviourSubject and toggle its value whenever the sidebar opens or closes

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, startWith } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SideMenuService {
  private open$ = new BehaviourSubject<boolean>(true);

  constructor() { }

  getOpen() {
    return this.open$;
  }

  swapOpen(value: boolean) {
    this.open$.next(value);
  }
}
```

In your component where you are looking at the component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SideMenuService } from "../../../services/side-menu/side-menu.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'side-menu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css']
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public open!: boolean;

  constructor(
    private sideMenuService: SideMenuService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sideMenuService.getOpen()
      .subscribe(result => this.open = result);
  }

  swtichTriggered(): void {
    this.sideMenuService.swapOpen(!this.open);
  }
}
```

One of the benefits of using a `Subject` over an `Observable` would be that it is *multicast* so only a single instance of the `Subject` will be used to pass value to its `Observers`.

The same behavior can be achieved in the `Observable` by using `share` operator which basically uses a `Subject` underneath its implementation.